# vendor.js is huge after npm run production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I am using Laravue Dashboard based on Laravel and Vue.js, running on an online server, not localhost, it is a fresh install, no edits has been conducted.

My Problem is :

After running npm run watch/dev or even npm run production, vendor.js is about 26MB which I find unreasonably big.

- I have tried to run npm run report but nothing shows, no errors or data.
- Webpack bundle analyzer plugin is configured but stats.json is empty.

Here are dependencies from package.json:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "resources/**/*.{js,vue}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "husky": "^3.0.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.1.2",
    "laravel-mix-eslint": "^0.1.3",
    "lint-staged": "^9.2.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.39.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "driver.js": "^0.9.7",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.11.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.5",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonlint": "^1.6.3",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "path-to-regexp": "^3.0.0",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.8.4",
    "tui-editor": "^1.4.5",
    "vue": "2.6.10",
    "vue-count-to": "^1.0.13",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.12.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-splitpane": "^1.0.4",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.0",
    "vuex": "3.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.4"
  }
```

In the official laravue demo https://laravue.dev/, vendor.js is ~4MB.

I cannot find any reason for this issue, would somebody offer any advise please?

Comment: Just grab yourself [https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) and then follow the instructions to add it as a plugin to webpack so you can preview it afterwards. It'll show you (with a GUI) exactly why its so big.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you for commenting, I have mentioned in my questions that webpack bundle analyzer is installed but not showing anything.. anyway my problem was memory related and has been simply by restarting server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

After hours of inspecting, I found out that " npm run production " wasn't finishing because of memory shortage, this is why no errors were returned, the process was killed at some point with no messages.

simply restarted server and re-ran command.. Worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you remove some package that is not needed, will reduce vendor file size more.